# How to minify an Angular 4 web application

Tags: angular, npm, minify

I'm building a web application with Angular 4 and `angular/cli: 1.3.1`
`node: 10.7.0`

Which plugin I can use to minify my app because, the `vendor.bundle` file size is about 8mb. I implemented lazy loading in the app.

I'm building the app from Jenkins with: `npm run build --prod --aot true --progress false`

If someone knows a plugin or has some tutorials, that will be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a production build ? (`ng build --configuration=production`)

Comment: @MartinPaucot i'm using this command npm run build --prod --aot true --progress false. I will try with your command.

Comment: @MartinPaucot no changes. The files have the same size.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question since without seeing things like your angular.json, package.json, tsconfig.ts, how your bundles are working, etc. It's tough to nail down what you're missing. However in angular.json -> configurations -> production make sure optimization: true, sourceMap: false, buildOptimizer:true, extractCss:true, vendorChunk:true, and just run `ng build --prod` in most cases if your CLI is configured right.

Comment: @MartinPaucot your command is only valid for an Angular 6 + project. So this isn't a good answer for this question.

Comment: Also things like Webpack Bundle Analyzer are handy to use occasionally to see if you're "tree shaking" well.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should use the appropriate CLI parameter.
In case of production build it will be

```
ng build --prod
```

In Angular production build files are minified and uglified.

You also asked about some guides so I include something more to read:

https://angular.io/guide/deployment

https://medium.com/@kavisha.talsania/angular-development-vs-production-build-671b7fd5dbf4

Comment: the build command code is optimized. The problem is the size of the files.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I use this commands

```
ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk --source-map=false
```

Comment: tested before, the problem is not related to how to use the command to build

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem was solved.
The solution?
Previously we make the build from jenkins with "npm run build --prod --aot true --progress false" and for some reason with that command the vendor file was named vendor.bundle.js and have a size o 8.3mb.
Now I changed that command by "ng build --prod --aot true --progress false" and the vendor file was named vendor.fdd67abb220f03081b41.bundle.js and have a size o 2.3mb.

Someone know why the new vendor has a hash in the name?